# What is the grammar of " a function of how socially connected you are to those around you"?

Tags: grammar

The whole sentence is "Loneliness is not a function of being alone, but rather, a function of how socially connected you are to those around you".

I don't know why not " how socially you are connected to those around you".It's what I think is usually used.What is the difference between the original sentence and mine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"How socially you are connected to..." has a slightly different meaning to "How socially connected you are to...". It is the meaning of "how" that is different in each case.

***How***, used in this way, can have one of two different senses. It can mean "the means by which", or it could mean "the extent to which".

***how socially you are connected...*** equals "the means by which socially you are connected".

***how socially connected you are...*** equals "the extent to which you are socially connected".

Comment: I see.How socially and how socially connected are different.Thanks!